# How to know an action is done globally react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

This is really common that i want to know an action is done and then do sth after that. for this we usually use events but i don't know how to use it in my case.

my scenario: There is an `SplashScene` which shows some animations for a constant time, after that time i navigate to my `HomeScene`. there are some other initializations which i don't want to be done unless `SplashScene` is gone and we r in `HomeScene`.

those initializations are in `App` component. and what im doing is that because the `SplashScene` animation time is constant i use a timeout to init things.

```
// Constants.ts
export const GlobalStaticData = {
    initialDuration: 5000 // ms
}
```

---

```
// App

    public componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // initialize things
        }, GlobalStaticData.initialDuration) // show dialogs after splash loading time
    }
```

---

```
// SplashScene

private onAnimationEnd = () => {
  NavigationActions.navigate(HomeScene)
}
```

but i know this is not good at all, i already experience sometimes which timing doesn't work as expected and things get initialized when app is still in `SplashScene`.

i was thinking for way to use `events` but i dont know how do that. what i want to listen to a value e.g called `isSplashLoadCompleted` in `App` component and in splash change that value when its works are done. then in `App` its event listener is called and initialing get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a basic event system to subscribe to an event and then emit the event when certain thing happened on the other page:

```
const subscribers = {}
// Subscribe to loading your target page here Ex subsciber('home_load',()=>{ Your Logic })
const subscribe = (event,callback)=>{
     if(subscribers[event] == null){ subscribers[event] = {}}
     subscribers[event].push(callback)

}

const unSubscribe = (event,callback)=>{
....
}
// Call this inside your target page componentDidMount Ex: emitEvent('home_load',Some data or null)
const emitEvent = (event,data)=>{
    if(subscribers[event]!=null && subscibers[event].length > 0){
         for(const cb of subscribers[event]){
             if(cb != null){cb()}
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the you want to trigger specific code when different scenes are loaded. I would recommend moving your animation/initialization logic into the compomentDidMount() for the respective scenes - SplashScene and HomeScene.

You're running into issues because your animation/initialization code is completely decoupled from your scenes. Couple the logic to the componentDidMount for these scenes and you won't have to worry about timing issues.

Comment: i love your idea but the point is i'm doing things in `App` that makes moving out the logic to another scene like `HomeScene` will not be possible. the things that im doing is not in context of my question so i removed them. so although i like your approach i can't accept that as the answer. tnx